# Python dataclass / attrs: enforce at least one of two fields is passed

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, mypy, python-dataclasses

I have the following class:

```
@dataclass
class PackageDefinition:
    alias: Optional[str] = None
    single_edition: bool = False
    remote_url: Optional[git.PathLike] = None
    local_repo: Optional[git.Repo] = None
    tag: Optional[git.Tag] = None
    version: Optional[semver.Version] = None
```

I want some kind of conditional constructor. If `single_edition` is True, then alias can be None, otherwise it must be set.

I can do this with a mypy overload:

```
from typing import overload, Literal, Optional
class PackageDefinition:
    alias: Optional[str] = None
    single_edition: bool = False
    remote_url: Optional[git.PathLike] = None
    local_repo: Optional[git.Repo] = None
    tag: Optional[git.Tag] = None
    version: Optional[semver.Version] = None

    @overload
    def __init__(self, alias: str, single_edition: Literal[False], remote_url: Optional[git.PathLike], ...) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self, alias: Optional[str], single_edition: Literal[True], remote_url: Optional[git.PathLike], ...) -> None: ...
```

... however then I also need to provide a concrete implementation of `__init__` to satisfy mypy and so I lose the benefit of dataclass.

Is there a way around this? Happy to use something else like attrs or NamedTuple if that helps.

Comment: Why are so many arguments optional? Seems odd that you can define a package definition with literally no information. I'm not sure a dataclass is the best fit for this class.

Comment: @chepner _just added the  `= None`_. The reason is because these classes are hydrated incrementally. So some subset of the info is known at the various places that construct these classes - e.g. one entry point knows about `local_repo` and `tag`, one knows `version` and `alias`, one knows `alias` and `remote_url`. I then define ways of mapping and comparing these different partial classes to see if they are all referring to the same underlying `package`. It's a bit of a mess

Comment: You might consider collecting the information *first*, and only after you have all the information instantiate the class. Is there really any difference between building up a list of arguments and modifying a "broken" instance until it's fully configured?

Comment: The process you are describing also sounds like what the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) was created to capture.

Comment: @chepner Thank you, good points, I'll have a think. I guess I was trying to keep everything *lazy* and only collect the information JIT because a lot of the hydrating is quite slow with git cloning and web requests. For example, if `single_edition = True` then I don't ever need to look up `alias` from the database, I can fall back to `remote_url` to compare two packages. I hadn't considered the builder pattern (that's the `pizza(diam=10).with_cheese("mozz").with_peppers().bake()` one right).

Comment: Basically :)  The idea is that you can instantiate `PackageDefinitionBuilder` with *no* arguments, and only call its "bake" method to produce a `PackageDefinition` instance when all the necessary information is available.

Comment: @chepner But why use a Builder Pattern when you can just tell python which arguments you are passing to its constructor?

Comment: The idea is to *not* allow partially initialized objects. `PackageDefinition` *only* works you can provide all the necessary arguments; a different class represents the partially initialized *potential* `PackageDefinition` until you finally  have all the values needed to make a fully initialized instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`__post_init__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing), for example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class PackageDefinition:
    alias: Optional[str] = None
    single_edition: bool = False

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not self.single_edition and self.alias is None:
            raise Exception("Alias not set")
```

Comment: +1 That's good, although not statically typed (PackageDefinition(single_edition=False) would ideally be an error for mypy, not just runtime)